# Saving output result in tabular format in same file or different file

Tags: python, list

I am trying to save the output of this program into a file, but I am getting errors while doing the same.

```
import csv
import random

with open('karyotype.zeamays1.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        lines = []
        colors = open("colours_bar.txt", "r")
        lines = colors.read().split()
        color_me = random.choice(lines)
        row.append(color_me)
        h = open("test.txt", "w")
        print row
```

The input files are as following :

karyotype.zeamays1.txt

```
    chr -   b73_chr1    B73-Chr1    0   301354135   
    chr -   b73_chr2    B73-Chr2    0   237068873   
    chr -   b73_chr3    B73-Chr3    0   232140174   
    chr -   b73_chr4    B73-Chr4    0   241473504   
    chr -   b73_chr5    B73-Chr5    0   217872852   
    chr -   w22_chr1    W22-Chr1    0   301354135
```

colours_bar.txt

```
    black
    dred 
    dpred
    vdgreen 
    pgreen
    vvdpgreen
```

When I print the rows,I get result as following :

```
['chr', '-', 'b73_chr1', 'B73-Chr1', '0', '301354135', '', 'black']
['chr', '-', 'b73_chr2', 'B73-Chr2', '0', '237068873', '', 'vdgreen']
['chr', '-', 'b73_chr3', 'B73-Chr3', '0', '232140174', '', 'vdpurple']
['chr', '-', 'b73_chr4', 'B73-Chr4', '0', '241473504', '', 'vdgreen']
['chr', '-', 'b73_chr5', 'B73-Chr5', '0', '217872852', '', 'vdppurple']
```

How to save this result into file in tabular format ?

EDIT after the comments :

```
with open('karyotype.zeamays1.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        lines=[]
        colors=open("colours_bar.txt","r")
        lines=colors.read().split()
        color_me=random.choice(lines)
        row.append(color_me)

    csvfile=open('lvg.csv','wb')
    spamwriter=csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter='\t',quotechar='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "tabular format".  How do you expect the output to appear?  Why is standard Python formatting not working for you?  You got exactly what you asked for: each row is a list of strings.  Did you want something like the input format, but with a colour appended to the end?

Comment: yes,I intend to do the same.and when I am trying to save the print result in a file,the format is getting distorted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) method. It works similar to the `csv.reader` method you used earlier in your code in that you can specify a delimiter, in this case `'\t'`, meaning a tab. This will split each item by a tab when you write it.

This is assuming you are trying to write to a csv file. If not, and you are only trying to print, you can try this:

```
'\t'.join(row)
```

EDIT:

```
with open('karyotype.zeamays1.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    csvfile=open('lvg.csv','wb')
    spamwriter=csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter='\t',quotechar='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in reader:
        lines=[]
        colors=open("colours_bar.txt","r")
        lines=colors.read().split()
        color_me=random.choice(lines)
        row.append(color_me)
        spamwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I tried csv.writer option.But the issue I am facing is the result isnt getting stored in the file..

Comment: Well I'm not sure what your new code looks like, but in your current code `    h = open("test.txt", "w")` opens the file to write but you never actually write anything to it.

Comment: I have added my current edit to the main query/program.

Comment: Take a look at the docs I linked in my answer. When you create a csv.writer object it doesn't actually write stuff until you call writerow. So in your case spamwriter.writerow(row).

Comment: Also watch out you are creating a csv.writer each time in your for-loop, it should be made outside then have it write a row each iteration.

Comment: HI,I tried to edit it,but still no table is saved in file.I will edit the main query to show you how my program looks now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102743/discussion-between-john-howard-and-shome).